# What is the angle between earth's axis of rotation and equator? Are they perpendicular or at 66 1/2 Degrees?

Tags: earth-rotation, earth-system, equator, axial-obliquity

By rotational axis I mean axial tilt or Axial obliquity or 66 1/2 degrees tilt of earth to its orbital.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you asking about the angle between the Earth's axis and its equator? They're defined as 90° apart...

Comment: You might be thinking of the ecliptic, the plane of the Earth's orbit around the Sun, but, as @DanielGriscom notes, the equator-pole angle is 90 degrees by definition.

Comment: I'm aware of equator-pole angle,  I wanted the angle between axis and equator. Thanks @DanielGriscom, your comment has answered the question.

Comment: Glad this helped you. It would be great if you clarified your question a bit; I'll then add my comment as an answer to help future visitors.

Comment: Is the question clear now,  do you want me to change in any other way?

Comment: @user1 Your question title and body both still mention "66 1/2 degrees" and you haven't stated why you think this figure might apply to the Earth, or why you think the axis might be at a different angle than the pole.